# How to change this regex replace from replacing a single word to replacing an array of words?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, replace

I've searched but cannot adapt anything to my code. I'm trying to make `var toReplace = "warming"` into an array `var toReplace = ['global', 'warming']` so it will replace every word from the array in input with var newWord which just wraps the word in a span. thanks for any help!

```
if (temperature > 90) {
    var input = 'ITS GLOBAL EFFING WARMING';
    var toReplace = "WARMING";
    var emphasisColor = 'cyan';
};

var newWord = `<span style="color: ${emphasisColor}">${toReplace}</span>`;
var regEx = new RegExp(toReplace,"g");
var output = input.replace(regEx, newWord);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`join` by `|` to alternate, so that either word in the array will match. Also make sure to use the `i` flag to make it case-insensitive.

Also put `$&` in the *replacement string* to echo the matched string (so that, for example, when `GLOBAL` is matched, the result is `<span style="color: cyan">GLOBAL</span>` rather than `<span style="color: cyan">global,warming</span>`:

```js
var input = 'ITS GLOBAL EFFING WARMING';
var toReplace = ['global', 'warming']
var emphasisColor = 'cyan';

var regEx = new RegExp(toReplace.join('|'),"gi");
var output = input.replace(regEx, `<span style="color: ${emphasisColor}">$&</span>`);
console.log(output);
```

Of course, this depends on `toReplace` not having any special characters. If it can have more than just word characters, you might [replace-escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) them all first.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `forEach` to execute a function for each element in the array:

```
if (temperature > 90) {
    var input = "ITS GLOBAL EFFING WARMING";
    var toReplace = ["GLOBAL", "WARMING"];
    var emphasisColor = "cyan";
};
toReplace.forEach((element, index) => {
    regEx = new RegExp(element, "gi");
    input = input.replace(regEx, `<span style="color: ${emphasisColor}">${toReplace[index]}</span>`);
});
```

You can also use a `for` loop instead of `forEach` to obtain the same result.

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: @CertainPerformance suggestion is way better and does not require forEach